# MySQL logs different time than NOW()

Tags: mysql, logging, time

MySQL server logs entries with different time than system or mysql itself:

```
mysql> select @@global.time_zone;
+--------------------+
| @@global.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| SYSTEM             |
+--------------------+
mysql> select NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2016-02-24 10:47:30 |
+---------------------+

# /var/log/mysql/mysql_queries.log
2016-02-24T18:47:11.191126Z    2 Connect        root@localhost on  using Socket
2016-02-24T18:47:11.191421Z    2 Query  select @@version_comment limit 1
2016-02-24T18:47:16.769493Z    2 Query  select @@global.time_zone
2016-02-24T18:47:30.503214Z    2 Query  select NOW()
```

Timestamp seems synced with log:

```
mysql> show variables;
timestamp               | 1456339753.062182 # 18:47
log_timestamps          | UTC
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution was super simple: look through the variables and try to locate relevant:

```
log_timestamps                   | UTC
```

So I changed it to 'SYSTEM':

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL  log_timestamps  = 'SYSTEM';

# /var/log/mysql/mysql_queries.log
2016-02-24T18:54:23.837289Z    2 Query  SET GLOBAL  log_timestamps  = 'SYSTEM'
2016-02-24T10:54:25.949232-08:00    2 Query     show variables
```

Time in log switched from 18:54 to 10:54 as should.

[From MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_timestamps):

> - log_timestamps
>
> **This variable controls the timestamp time zone** of error log messages,
>   and **of general query log and slow query log messages written to files**.
>   It does not affect the time zone of general query log and slow query
>   log messages written to tables (mysql.general_log, mysql.slow_log).
>   Rows retrieved from those tables can be converted from the local
>   system time zone to any desired time zone with CONVERT_TZ() or by
>   setting the session time_zone system variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the change persistant after mysql restar or a reboot put this into your my.cnf file:

```
log_timestamps   = 'SYSTEM'
```